# TypeScript and event.target || event.srcElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, dom-events

I am new to TypeScript, and rewriting an arrow function in React.js.

This is what it currently looks like:

```
  handleChange = (event): void => {
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    this.setState({
      value: target.value
    });
  };
```

`handleChange()` doesn't return anything and only mutates `state`, so it's type is set to `void`.

What types should `event` and `target` have in this scenario? I need to support the widest range of browsers possible and so this is why `target` could be `event.target` or `event.srcElement`, if `event.target` is undefined.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED FUNCTION:**

```
  handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event is of the type `React.MouseEvent`, target will depend on the element that's being clicked on.  You can pass in the element as a generic type to the MouseEvent type, so there's no need to explicitly type the target element, as that will be determined by the generic.  For example:

```
handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    const target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    this.setState({
      value: target.value
    });
  };
```

would be accurate if the element being clicked is a standard HTML button element.

**EDIT:** Looks like I forgot non-mouse events exist.  Similar types exist in React type definitions for most all commonly used events.  If you're handling a custom event or the appropriate type doesn't exist, use `SyntheticEvent`.  If you're looking for a specific event, try searching through the [official typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts).

Also note that Typescript types will have no bearing on browser support.  Typescript really only exists in development to enforce more thoughtful programming habits and prevent errors, but it's ultimately transpiled to regular JavaScript before being deployed, so an inaccurate typing will not have tangible consequences provided that it compiles (apart from bugs it might cause).

Comment: This is really interesting. I changed `<HTMLButtonElement>` to `<HTMLInputElement>` because I'm dealing with radio buttons—this made sense to me. I also changed `React.MouseEvent` to `React.ChangeEvent` as I was getting an error on my `onChange` prop and this was recommended. I am now getting an error regarding `event.srcElement`. I've included it in my edit above.

Comment: What element is it applied to? I have a change handler on an input typed as: ```const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    };``` without any errors.  It's probably ```srcElement```, seems it's a browser-specific alias for ```target``` that only exists in IE, so the typings don't support it.  If you have to use that property, you may end up having to ```//@ts-ignore it```, but ```target``` is supported in all versions of IE, so it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Will post the updated function above. TY for answering my question.